# AppSettings when running a .NET application from a server share

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

In order to simplify deployment (i.e. not have to build an installer), I'm wanting to deploy my .NET WinForms app to a server share on our local intranet.  Turns out this is harder than I thought. I've done what I was told to do [and generated a strong key for my application](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jhermiz/archive/2007/08/14/60284.aspx).  I've also referenced the key in the project settings.

When I run the application from the server, it runs but the application configuration is empty, i.e. this returns null:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]
```

I'm not sure where to put the app.config file, or how to tell the application where to read it from.

Can anyone help me out here?

I've got a feeling this is going to be just the first of many potential issues.

Comment: Are you deploying this as a ClickOnce app, or are you compiling it and copying it to your network share?

When you compile, the app.config should get turned into MyApp.dll.config - does this file exist in the deployment location?

Comment: Tried this and it works!  Please add as the answer Dave, so I can give you a tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile, the app.config should get turned into MyApp.dll.config and needs to live in the deployment location

Comment: Although Visual Studio does create MyApp.dll.config files on DLL's, these are ignored in a deployed application.  All configuration data for a DLL must get merged with the executable's config file (MyApp.EXE.config) in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

The App.Config file of the application must be in the same directory as the executable.  However, bear in mind that it will NOT be called "App.Config".  It will be named the same as the executable, followed with a ".config" extension.